# How to include Token in Header using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework, rest

**I am working with `Token Authentication` using `Django REST Framework`. I am generating a new token during `User Registration`. I need to pass this token to the frontend including in `header`.** These are my code:

`settings.py:`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    ...
]
```

`urls.py:` (project level)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),

]
```

`urls.py:` (app level)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.Register.as_view({"post":"register"}), name='users'),
    path('login/', views.Login.as_view({"post":"create"}), name='login'),
    path('profile/', views.Profile.as_view({"get":"list"}), name='profile'),

]
```

`views.py:`

```
# Register View
class Register(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.CreateModelMixin,):
   serializer_class = UserRegisterSerializer

   def register(self, request):

      data_dict = self.request.data

      firstname = data_dict['firstname']
      lastname = data_dict['lastname']
      username = data_dict['username']
      email = data_dict['email']
      password = data_dict['password']
      mobile = data_dict['mobile']

      data = userRegistrationModel.objects.create(firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname, username=username, email=email, password=password, mobile=mobile)

      if data:
          user = data.set_password(password)
          data.save()
          token = Token.objects.create(user=data)

          return Response({"message": "Registered Successfully", "code": "HTTP_201_CREATED", "Token": token.key})
      else:
          return Response({"message": "Sorry Try Next Time!!!",  "code": "HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN"})



# Login View
class Login(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.CreateModelMixin,):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        data_dict = self.request.data

        email = data_dict['email']
        password = data_dict['password']

        data = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if data:
            users = Token.objects.filter(user=data).first()

            userData = UserRegisterSerializer(data)

            return Response({"message": "Login Successfully",  "code": "HTTP_200_OK", "token": users.key, "user": userData.data})

        else:
            return Response({"message": "Invalid Login",  "code": "HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED"})


# Profile View
class Profile(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

    def list(self, request, pk):
        queryset = userRegistrationModel.objects.get(id=pk)
        serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
        ...
        ...
```

[This is screenshot of generating the Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpEcS.png)

**Till here (while generating the new Token) it is working perfectly. Now when I am `including this Token` in `LoginView` then it is not validating.**

**Is there any best way `to send this Token` to the frontend by including in header or `if we can update` the previous Token by new Token `in Login View`.**

**I am not getting that how to work with `Django REST Framework` default `authtoken`. Please guide me what is the standard process of using Token Based Authentication.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a token like this in Django rest framework.

```
KEY :  Authorization
VALUE : Token <token-value>
```

in your e.g.

```
return Response(
    {
        "message": "Login Successfully",
        "code": "HTTP_200_OK",
        "Authorization": "Token "+users.key,
        "user": userData.data
    }
)
```

> curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/example/ -H 'Authorization:
> Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b'

Refer this https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Comment: Thanks for answering. Please tell me one thing while testing in Postman then what should be the API Type under Authorization? Like we have option there as API Key, Basic Auth, Bearer Token and etc.

Comment: And also I tried this in command prompt:  

`curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profile/ -H 'Authorization: Token b0f99371041ac66c1bab31cbc6c6a1f510faf53e'`



But it it giving error as 

`{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Token
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: b0f99371041ac66c1bab31cbc6c6a1f510faf53e' `